# LINQ can't convert to 'int?'

Tags: c#, list, linq, sorting

I am trying to sort by multiple criteria whereas I have to return the Id of the most expensive car and if there are multiple cars with the same value then return the newest car based on manufacture date.

```
public int? Exercise7demo(List<Car> cars)
{
    if (cars == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    else
    {
        List<Car> sorted = cars
            .OrderByDescending( x => x.SuggestedRetailPrice )
            .ThenBy( x => x.ManufacturedDate )
            .ToList();

        return sorted.ID;
    } 
}
```

It is getting stuck because I can't wrap my head around why it won't return "sorted". I says specifically "Can't explicitly convert type System.Collections.Generic.List to 'int?'

What am I missing? Please note that I can't change the public type to make this work, I have thought of that but this is part of an online demo course I am doing so this is the setup.

EDIT: I should clarify that ID is original defined and is part of the public int? statement (sorry terminology might be off here). For some reason, If I try to recall .ID in the return statement, it says it is not defined. Is that because of my List sorted = cars statement?

Thanks!

Comment: Your posted code does not return a `List<Car>`. Where is this `.ID` property defined? It is not a member of `List<Car>` either.

Comment: See comment below. I think I have overwritten the original List<Car> cars so the ID is not defined anymore?

Comment: If you read your code, you have a list of `Car`, and you are trying to get the ID of a specific `Car`. If I was to give you a list of cars written on a piece of paper, then ask for the ID of "the Car", you would look at me confused right?

Comment: I think you have misunderstood. I added clarifying information in EDIT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
return cars.OrderByDescending(x => x.SuggestedRetailPrice).ThenBy(x => x.ManufacturedDate).FirstOrDefault().ID;
```

You do not need to convert to list. Even more, it may impact the performance (from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261(v=vs.110).aspx)):

> The ToList(IEnumerable) method forces immediate query evaluation and returns a List that contains the query results.

So, the suggested way solves your problem and keep the evaluation lazy.

Comment: This is what I had initially tried but got tripped up by appending .List() to the end. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

After the sorting criteria, you have applied `ToList()` which means you'd still get a `List<Car>`, not an `int`.

You'd have to change that to:

```
return sorted.FirstOrDefault().ID;
```

You might also want to check for any null value, so:

```
return sorted.FirstOfDefault()?.ID;
```

Answer (score 1):

your sorted is a list. In order to return top item you can use first which will return first value.

Try like this

```
return sorted.First().ID;
```

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion. It says that "ID" is not defined in the current list. Did I make a mistake by creating a list with the same name as the initial one in the public statement?

Comment: That's mean there is no property name ID in the list

Comment: But If I can use that definition of ID earlier, before I redefine List<Car> cars. I know it is defined originally.

Answer (score 0):

Sorted is a list of card, but you only want the id of the first car of the list.  So use : return sorted.First().ID
It will return the ID of the first car of the list.